# How to Scroll the web content loaded on UIWebView to a specific division/content start point?

Tags: iphone, iphone-standalone-web-app

I am new to iPhone apps Development.

I am developing an application in which i need to scroll the webpage loaded on UIWebView to a certain div having some Id. Since I am loading the static webpage by converting the web content into a string. String contains some anchor tags appear on the HTML page. so clicking on the anchor tag webView should scroll automatically to particular div containing the same title as the anchor tag's title is.

I am using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString.`

I have used a lot of javascript available on the net as well as on the stack overflow but none was feasible in my case.

Is there any solution for my problem.